# How to count a temporary variable in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a personal analytics project and I need to filter a SQL table. My SQL knowledge is very basic and moreover, I know that in Oracle but in this case I have to use SQLite and it seems to be quite different.

For example, suppose the table is

```
    student physics chemistry maths history english
    Brian 78 62 100 40 50
    Bill 80 70 95 50 60
    Brian 80 40 90 95 60
```

The table has repetition. 
I asked a question earlier today, using the same example above, which would let me rank the subjects for each student. 
[How to RANK multiple columns of an entire table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720978/how-to-rank-multiple-columns-of-an-entire-table)

What I want to do now is find out which students had Maths in the top 3 among all subjects and group the table for each student. So the goal is to find out how many times did Brian have Maths in Top 3 of his scores.

IT WeiHan's answer to the previous question (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bjui5W1VWmHXcqKAhK5iBD/0 ) worked perfectly and displayed the rank of the subjects for each row. I used their answer and tried to modify it for this purpose.

```
with cte as (
  select student,'physics' as class,physics as score from Table1 union all
  select student,'chemistry' as class,chemistry as score  from Table1 union all
  select student,'maths' as class,maths as score  from Table1 union all
  select student,'history' as class,history as score  from Table1 union all
  select student,'english' as class,english as score  from Table1 
)

SELECT name,class,score,rnk,
(CASE 
WHEN class = "maths" AND rnk <=3 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) as maths_rank

FROM
(select  student,class,score,RANK() OVER (partition by student order by score desc) rnk
from cte)
```

which gives a table like

```
name class score rnk maths_rank
Brian maths 100 1 1
```

I want to be able to count the `maths_rank` values or sum it (as it contains 1 or 0 values) and group the table on student name. I tried to count the `maths_rank` variable but that didn't work and resulted in errors. Please help me out with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are on the right path.  I think you just need a `where` clause:

```
with cte as (
      select student,'physics' as class,physics as score from Table1 union all
      select student,'chemistry' as class,chemistry as score  from Table1 union all
      select student,'maths' as class,maths as score  from Table1 union all
      select student,'history' as class,history as score  from Table1 union all
      select student,'english' as class,english as score  from Table1 
    )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by student order by score desc) as subject_rank
      from cte t
     ) t
where class = 'maths' and subject_rank <= 3;
```

Edit:

If you want the number of times maths was in the top 3, then:

```
select student, sum(case when class = 'maths' and subject_rank <= 3 then 1 else 0 end) as maths_top3
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by student order by score desc) as subject_rank
      from cte t
     ) t
group by student;
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but I get the "Uncaught Error:  no such table: t" error. 
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Plus the point wasn't finding out the ranks of Maths. That has been done. The point was finding out how many times did Brian have Maths in Top 3, which is what I want to find out.